# TRIGGER or REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW in the background

Tags: postgresql, triggers, materialized-views, postgresql-9.6

Is it possible to execute a trigger (right now it will contain a refresh materialized view, but if there is a general solution, that would be better) in the background?

So that the query returns before the trigger finishes?

We have quite complicated materialized views for performance considerations, and we'd like to keep them up to date, possibly with triggers. However that would defeat the purpose of the materialized views, if we'd have to wait for the refresh to finish before every update operation returns successfully.

Thanks,

Comment: [Refresh a materialized view automatically using a rule or notify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23906977/1995738).