# Triggers to refresh multiple materialized views based on same table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis, materialized-views

I have a spatial table in a Postgres database from which I create three separate materialized views (each based on specific spatial queries). I want to create trigger functions to refresh each of the materialized views on updates, inserts, and deletes.

I have created three separate functions and triggers, but the performance (as to be expected) is horrendous. If I run a single trigger on update, insert, or delete, it performs fine. Below is a sample function and trigger I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mvw_taxa_hex5km()   
RETURNS trigger 
AS $BODY$ 
  BEGIN 
    refresh materialized view mvw_taxa_hex5km; 
    return new; 
  END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 


CREATE TRIGGER refresh_mvw_taxa_hex5km   
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON occurrence   
FOR EACH STATEMENT   
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_mvw_taxa_hex5km();
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I considered running scheduled tasks, but I really need the refresh on changes to the table. I have read a little about "concurrently," but not sure if this is the answer.

Comment: Refreshing materialized view is something like `truncate table foo; insert into foo <query_behind_materialized_vie>`. So when you changes every single row, you then refreshes whole data in the materialized view each time. Are you sure that you are using materialized views in the right way?

Comment: Well, the short answer is no, I am not sure I am using materialized views in the right way. Based on my reading, though, a materialized view is what I need for my workflow.

Comment: You may be interested in [Refresh a materialized view automatically using a rule or notify.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23906977/1995738)

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this further.